# Possible to update a field in Sales Quota Distribution records associated with an Opportunity when Opportunity Owner is changed?

Tags: dynamics-crm, workflow, microsoft-dynamics, power-automate

One Opportunity record can have many Sales Quota Distribution records associated to it.  I want to be able to update the Opportunity's Owner field, and pass whatever is in the Owner field to EACH Sales Quota Distribution record associated to it.  I have created a text field in the Sales Quota Distribution entity called "Opportunity Owner" that I want the Owner of the Opportunity record to get passed to.  Is this possible?  If so, how?

If not, would it help if I changed my "Opportunity Owner" field in the Sales Quota Distribution entity to a lookup field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't update child entity records' fields in OOB Dynamics CRM workflow. As an alternative, you may create a custom workflow activity (using CRM SDK C# Code) that you can run on the update of Opportunity Owner. And what that code will do is:

- Get all related Sales Quota Distribution entity records
- Update "Opportunity Owner" field on each Sales Quota Distribution record
- Update entity records in CRM

To check how to create custom workflow activity please see the documentation on to the below link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/workflow/workflow-extensions